# Simple routing views

Tags: angularjs

I am just starting study Angular and trying example from book, but my simple routing doesn't work.

**I have updated code as was recommended in the answers**

Here is index.html:

```
<html ng-app="airline">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>AngulAir</h1>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js:

```
angular.module('airline', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(airlineRouter);

function airlineRouter ($routeProvider) {
    info('1');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {template: '<h3>test</h3>'})
};
```

When I refresh the page I don't have 'test' in the browser and don't have alert message.  Why ?  What I am missing ?

**Update**

Here is a full code example:  https://github.com/demas/ang_test

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest angular library use external router so you need to inject ngRoute and pass it as:

```
angular.module('airline', ['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: I did it and updated my answer, bit it didn't help me.

Comment: I have created git repository with my code - https://github.com/demas/ang_test.  Hope it will help to find my mistake

Comment: I have found the reason.  I can not use info() in this function.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ngRoute` directive. Download ng-route.js file and reference it in your HTML like;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And change your app.js like

```
angular.module('airline', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(airlineRouter);

function airlineRouter ($routeProvider) {
    info('1');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {template: '<h3>test</h3>'})
};
```

Comment: I did it and updated my answer, bit it didn't help me.

Comment: I have created git repository with my code - https://github.com/demas/ang_test.  Hope it will help to find my mistake

Comment: I have found the reason.  I can not use info() in this function.